# ASP.NET - Format date from database

Tags: c#, asp.net, date

I am retrieving information from my database and storing it in a reader.  The contents of the reader are then used to bind a repeater.

Everything works fine.  The only thing that is bugging me is that the date is displayed as 2012-01-01 00:00:00.  I want the last part (that is, 00:00:00) to be removed.

How can this be done please?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are trying to do is use the following:

```
   <asp:TemplateColumn>
   <ItemTemplate>
   <%#
   DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"database_field _name","{0:dd.MM.yyyy}")%>
   </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateColumn>
```

Code from [this forum post.](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t106201-date-format-in-repeater-control.html) However, change the dd.MM.yyyy to T as per [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx)

Comment: No problems. Happy to help! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you *may* want:

```
foo.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

although it would be better to use the "short date" [standard format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx):

```
foo.ToString("d");
```

... which would use the appropriate format for the thread's current culture. If you *are* going to use a [custom format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx), you may well want to explicitly state the culture you want to use (potentially the invariant one); if you don't know what culture you'll be using, you don't really know whether that format is suitable for the culture.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
dr.GetDateTime[3].ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Comment: Misread the question... Thank you.  On a side note, just got a fresh cup of coffee...

Comment: Wait you misread question then changed it to suit your answer?